# What does the & do in this case?

Tags: c++, vector

I had the following code today:

```
std::vector<float>& vecHighRes = highRes->getSamples();

PMHighResolution.cpp / .h

std::vector<float>& getSamples();
static std::vector<float> fSamples;

std::vector<float>& PMHighResolution::getSamples()
{
    return fSamples;
}
```

Why would I need the & twice there?
in the return I assume because it otherwise generates a copy of the vector to be returned, but why do I need it in the assign operator (

`std::vector<float>& vecHighRes = highRes->getSamples();`
) ?

Comment: The ampersand is there in the assignment because you want to say, "`vecHighRes` points to `highRes->getSamples()`", rather than "`vecHighRes` contains the same data as `highRes->getSamples()`". The ampersand is there in the function because you want to pass the reference and not the value.

Comment: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/overview-refs.html

Comment: getSamples() returns by reference. similarly, vecHighRes accepts the fSamples by reference. It is as simple as trying to remove copy constructor call in both the places.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `&` on the LHS means that `vecHighRes` is a reference:

```
std::vector<float>& vecHighRes = highRes->getSamples();
```

If you had omitted the `&`, `vecHighRes` would be a copy of vector `fSamples`, constructed from the reference returned by `getSamples`.

It is the same as this:

```
int a = 42;
int& b = a;  // b is a reference to a
int c = b;   // c is a copy of a
```

Answer (score 1):

`getSamples()` returns a reference

```
std::vector<float>& vecHighRes = highRes->getSamples();
```

with `&` ,  `vecHighRes` is a reference to `std::vector<float>`. No `fSamples` is copied after `highRes->getSamples()` gets called.

```
std::vector<float> vecHighRes = highRes->getSamples();
```

In this case, vecHighRes is a vector of float. getSamples will make a whole vector copies.

You may see lots of this kind forms in function parameter

```
 void func(std::vector<float>& vecHighRes, // pass by reference only. only reference is copied
           std::vector<float> vecHighRes2) // pass by value, whole vector is copied
```

Answer (score 0):

Because, in that way you are assigning a reference to a reference. If you'd omit the reference for vecHighRes, the assignment operator will copy the contents of the vector returned by get samples to the new vector.

Comment: That's not an assignment, it's an initialization